# bug when" new"custom uitablecellview apprear

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i am using a custom uitablecellview like i used to do .But ,unfortunately ,this time an exception is thrown when a new cell appears.So,the same portion of code have worked perfectly many times before .The only difference is that the quality of images that i put into cells is very high.
Did you have ideas?or should i explain more?
**Edit**
some code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellView";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SPViewControllCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell=cellView;
    self.cellView=nil;
}
UILabel *itemTitle=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
[itemTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Renaissance" size:24]];
itemTitle.text=[titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImageView *img=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
img.image=[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

The exception :
"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f36be0'
"
Thank you.

Comment: What exception? It could be a memory problem or a file format problem.

Comment: Any chance to see some code? Or what exception is thrown? also heavy images used may indicate that you're running into low memory problems

Comment: seems like either titles or images have been recycled and one of them has had it's address used by cell

Comment: @CiNN i don't understand the second part of your comment "one of them has had it's address used by cell " ,but what i can say is that "titles" and "images" are  NSArrays.

Comment: @Dingua: Are "titles" and "images" NSArray ??

Comment: @diwup :yes,i explain more:when cell appeared at the first time (when the view appears) all things is right but when scrolling ,when the first cell appears it crashs giving the exception listed before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing but is `titles` an array created with something like:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad(){
   // this will give you an autoreleased object
   titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Foo",...];
   // titles will be released once the current event is handled


   // try the alloc/init style method
   titles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:... ];
   // this will create an array with the retain count still at 1, thus won't be released
```

Same goes for `images`.

What you have is the classic memory management issue where a reference you think points to say an `NSArray` but in fact that array is long gone and happenes to have be replaced my a some random other object.

For completness:

```
- (void) viewDidUnload {
    // clean up after your self 
    [titles release];
    [images release];
}
```

Comment: hmm..i see it.my nsarrays were  in memory cache ,and when it will be fulled they are removed from cache

Comment: which is a good thing (normally) just you need to make sure they stick around. All the [NSThingy thingWith] style methods return an autoreleased object, which is great, use it and let it die, if you want to check the object, either use [[NSThingy alloc] initWith] style or assign it to a @property that has (retain) as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception description it seems that you are calling ** objectAtIndex:** method from a UITableViewCell class instance.

My question, in your code, what are the class type of your **images** and **titles** ivar?

Comment: for images:"UIImage"  and titles:"NSString"

Comment: @Dingua: your comments are misleading. You said they were NSString but now you accepted the answer assuming they were NSArray.

Comment: i thought that you talked about the type of the objects on the NSArrays.excuse me if i mislead you!and thank you a lot.